# How to write sql to do one aggregation over another

Tags: sql, oracle

Sample data

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 'UK'  "CUST_GRP", '00001' "CUST_ID", 'John'  "CUST_NAME", '001' "ORDER_ID", 'Beer' "GOODS" From Dual Union All
            Select 'ITA' "CUST_GRP", '00002' "CUST_ID", 'Jack'  "CUST_NAME", '002' "ORDER_ID", 'Coca Cola' "GOODS" From Dual Union All
            Select 'ITA' "CUST_GRP", '00002' "CUST_ID", 'Jack'  "CUST_NAME", '003' "ORDER_ID", 'Fanta' "GOODS" From Dual Union All
            Select 'ITA' "CUST_GRP", '00003' "CUST_ID", 'Lisa'  "CUST_NAME", '004' "ORDER_ID", 'Beer' "GOODS" From Dual Union All
            Select 'ITA' "CUST_GRP", '00003' "CUST_ID", 'Lisa'  "CUST_NAME", '005' "ORDER_ID", 'Coffee' "GOODS" From Dual Union All
            Select 'FRA' "CUST_GRP", '00004' "CUST_ID", 'Messi' "CUST_NAME", '006' "ORDER_ID", 'Wine' "GOODS" From Dual Union All
            Select 'FRA' "CUST_GRP", '00004' "CUST_ID", 'Messi' "CUST_NAME", '007' "ORDER_ID", 'Juice' "GOODS" From Dual Union All
            Select 'FRA' "CUST_GRP", '00004' "CUST_ID", 'Messi' "CUST_NAME", '008' "ORDER_ID", 'Beer' "GOODS" From Dual Union All
            Select 'FRA' "CUST_GRP", '00005' "CUST_ID", 'Mary'  "CUST_NAME", '009' "ORDER_ID", 'Wine' "GOODS" From Dual Union All
            Select 'FRA' "CUST_GRP", '00005' "CUST_ID", 'Mary'  "CUST_NAME", '020' "ORDER_ID", 'Else' "GOODS" From Dual 
        )
```

I need to know the number of customers that have done the same      number of orders.

Expected result should be either

| TEXT |
| --- |
| the amount of customers who ordered 1 times is 1 |
| the amount of customers who ordered 2 times is 3 |
| the amount of customers who ordered 3 times is 1 |

OR

| Orders | Customers |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |

Anyone can tell me how to write this SQL ?

Comment: can you explain in detail how you reached the result?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please show your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it. And provide a description of the algorithm in general words

Comment: you are describing group and aggregate functions

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the desired results. You are grouping by customer to find out how many orders they placed. Then grouping that subset as well.

```
select orders, count(*) customers
from (
   select cust_id, count(*) orders
   from tbl
   group by cust_id
   )
group by orders
```